# Ambari fail on startup. No logs to check

Tags: centos, centos7

I'm trying to start Ambari with just `ambari-server start` but I am getting this error

```
Waiting for server start..../usr/bin/sh: /var/log/ambari-server/ambari-server.out: No such file or directory
.....
ERROR: Exiting with exit code -1. 
REASON: Ambari Server java process died with exitcode 1. Check /var/log/ambari-server/ambari-server.out for more information.
```

However `/var/log/ambari-server/ambari-server.out` does not exist.

Couple questions-

Why does it not exist? What in the world is `exitcode 1`?

I'm using CentOS 7

PS: Ambari is not a tag? Am I posting in the wrong SE forums?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it doesn't exist yet you might want to create that log directory then (with suitable permissions) as for many applications the inability to write to the log file is a reason by itself to fail to start.

Exit codes are a method a command/script/process can use to indicate succes/failure. A command which exits with a zero exit status has succeeded. Typically a [non-zero exit status indicates failure.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status) Checking exit codes allows proper handling of failures, such as in your case, notification of the operator.

Comment: Just a question- Do you have any idea why it doesn't exits? Last time I had to start up ambari was 2 months ago and I had to start it again and the file was missing.